# How to use system font in Qtextbrowser

Tags: qtextbrowser, system-font

I am writing a Qt application, and I would like to use system's default fonts in the `QTextBrowser`. Is there any way to query what the default system font is, and set the same in `QTextBrowser`?

The following snippet shows what I have now:

```
QString line;
    QFont myfont ("Monospace");
    myfont.setPixelSize(12);
    myfont.setBold(true);
    line.append("Hello!\n\n");
    this->MessageBrowser->setTextColor(Qt::blue);
    this->MessageBrowser->append(line);
    this->MessageBrowser->setFont(myfont);
    line.append("Hello Again!\n\n");
    this->MessageBrowser->setTextColor(Qt::red);
    this->MessageBrowser->append(line);
    this->MessageBrowser->setFont(myfont);
```

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Devendra

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Use `setStyleHint` function, which will try to locate the closest match to the requested font on a target machine.

```
QString line;

    QFont myfont ("Monospace");
    myfont.setStyleHint(QFont::Monospace);
    myfont.setPixelSize(12);
    myfont.setBold(true);
    line.append("Hello!\n\n");
    this->MessageBrowser->setTextColor(Qt::blue);
    this->MessageBrowser->append(line);
    this->MessageBrowser->setFont(myfont);
    line.append("Hello Again!\n\n");
    this->MessageBrowser->setTextColor(Qt::red);
    this->MessageBrowser->append(line);
    this->MessageBrowser->setFont(myfont);

    this->MessageBrowser->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);
```

Although I am still not sure whether this is the perfect solution.

Devendra